# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.internal.connection.Cluster.selectServer

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am new to Apache Spark and I am using Scala and Mongodb to learn it.
https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala-api/
I am trying to read the RDD from my MongoDB database, my notebook script as below:

```
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
import com.mongodb.spark._

val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb+srv://root:root@mongodbcluster.td5gp.mongodb.net/test_database.test_collection?retryWrites=true&w=majority"))

val testRDD = MongoSpark.load(sc, readConfig)
print(testRDD.collect)
```

At the print(testRDD.collect) line, I got this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.mongodb.internal.connection.Cluster.selectServer(Lcom/mongodb/selector/ServerSelector;)Lcom/mongodb/internal/connection/Server;

And more than 10 lines "at..."

Used libraries:

```
org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.1
org.mongodb.scala:mongo-scala-driver_2.12:4.2.3
```

Is this the problem from Mongodb internal libraries or how could I fix it?

Many thanks

Comment: how did you package the jar? assembly build?

Comment: Ah, I am using Databricks to code. The libraries that I installed are from Maven.

Comment: I am using Databricks and Notebook to code. I don't use any Jars. 
I already tested with Python Script for the same feature and it also returns the same error

Comment: what Databricks runtime is used?

Comment: I tried both 7.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12) and 8.3 (includes Apache Spark 3.1.1, Scala 2.12)
Both of them return the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is a conflict between `mongo-spark-connector` and `mongo-scala-driver`.  The former is using Mongo driver 4.0.5, but the later is based on the version 4.2.3. I would recommend to try only with  `mongo-spark-connector`

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem, solved it using `mongo-spark-connector-2.12:3.0.1` jar and with that also added jar of `Scalaj HTTP » 2.4.2`. It's working fine now.